# Ngrx actions with enum types issue

Tags: typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

Hey all i'm attempting to build out actions/reducers/etc but i'm running into a frustrating TypeScript issue. I'm attempting to use string enums for the action type but it's failing to compile with the following:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
import { Action, ActionReducerMap } from '@ngrx/store';

export enum AnnoSetsTypes {
  ADD_MANY = '[AnnoSets] Add Many',
  RESET = '[AnnoSets] Reset',
}

export class AddMany implements Action {
  readonly type = AnnoSetsTypes.ADD_MANY;

  constructor(public annoSets: any[]) { }
}

export class Reset implements Action {
  readonly type = AnnoSetsTypes.RESET;
}

export type AnnoSetsAction = AddMany | Reset;

export interface IAnnoSetsState {
  annoSets: any[];
}

export function annoSetsReducer(
  state: IAnnoSetsState = { annoSets: [] },
  action: AnnoSetsAction
): IAnnoSetsState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AnnoSetsTypes.ADD_MANY:
      return { annoSets: [...action.annoSets] };
    case AnnoSetsTypes.RESET:
      return { annoSets: [] };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export interface State {
  annoSets: IAnnoSetsState;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State> = { // <-- COMPILE ERROR HERE
  annoSets: annoSetsReducer,
};
```

I'm currently using the following:

- Typescript 2.6.2
- Ngrx 4.1.1

Here's a repo with the trimmed down issue: https://github.com/cha55son/ngrx-action-type-issue

Some things to note. I don't want to cast the enums to strings because it causes type narrowing to fail in the switch statement. Also it seems to work just fine here: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/example-app/app/core/actions/layout.ts#L3 so i'm assuming there is some TypeScript configuration I need to set. As far as I can tell the code should be sufficient. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `tsconfig.json`, the setting `strict: true` also sets `strictFunctionTypes: true`, which causes the error. Disabling `strictFunctionTypes` explicitly should clear it.

`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "strict": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": false
  },
  "compileOnSave": true
}`

Comment: It seems `strictFunctionTypes` was introduced in 2.6 leading to my confusion.